# Is it possible to handle such URL

Tags: .htaccess

http://www.example.com/http://www.test.com

I have tried many different methods using .htaccess with no luck. I need to get that second url coming as parameter. Is it possible to redirect it to index.php and get it as `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or other method? Thanks

UPD: Looks like it is impossible to get whole URL, question marks are not recognized. Ideal example:

```
127.0.0.1/http://www.test.com/script.php?a=hello&b=world#blabla;par2?%par3
```

and i need to get in my index.php exact string

```
www.test.com/script.php?a=hello&b=world#blabla;par2?%par3
```

Comment: Is it acceptable if the URL was http://www.mysite.com/index.php?url=http://www.test.com ?  If so, parsing the URL parameter should be easy work with PHP.

Comment: Not really, if I type in address bar http://www.mysite.com/http://www.test.com I will get 403 error

Comment: I think he wants to know how to escape colons/semicolons for mod_rewrite.

Comment: yes, semicolons causing the 403 error, if i try http://127.0.0.1/http///  - works great now, but id i put ":" after http - it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.google.com/

As to how, it's been [covered on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/56082/configure-apache-to-handle-all-requests-via-single-index-php) already

Comment: Try option 2 but change the last line to
`RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.php?url=$1`
Everything that isn't index.php will redirect to index.php passing the URL specified as a get argument 'url'.

Comment: the 1st solution (on ServerFault) doesn't work perfectly: $1 cannot handle "?" symbol. That means if my .htaccess is 
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(?<!index\.php)(.*) http://example.com/index.php?url=$1
and I will request www.mysite.com/http://www.test.com/?par=1 -- it cuts "?par=1" and result will be http://www.test.com/

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem:**

This is a problem with **Apache** running on **Windows**. Apache on Windows does not let you have a colon (`:`) in your **REQUEST URI**. This is basically for avoiding URLs like http://www.mysite.com/C:/SomeFile.exe but is actually annoying.

If you use `mod_rewrite` at the same time it will be skipped.

You and some applications (like wikipedia) uses colon `:` in URL. so what to do in Apache on Windows?

**The Solution:**

At the time of writing this answer this bug still persists and there is no absolute solution, **BUT** there is a trick:

You may change your URL to something like this:
http://www.mysite.com/url/http://www.test.com

in this example `http://www.mysite.com/` is your **SCRIPT PATH** and `/url/http://www.test.com` is your **REQUEST URI**.

The problem will be gone if there is a **Slash** (`/`) before **Colon** (`:`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URI but only without the fragment since that is not transmitted to the server. Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^http:/ index.php [L]
```

Then the requested URI path plus query (so the part from the third `/` up to the first `#` or the end of the URI) is available at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: anyway i'm getting 403 (Access forbidden) error, that's because of colons (:) in the URL. I try 127.0.0.1/http://www.test.com

Comment: @Vitaly: And what does the server’s error and access log say?

Comment: error_log says "[Thu May 27 22:01:08 2010] [error] [client ::1] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET /http://hjh HTTP/1.1 to file"
access_log says "127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2010:21:03:17 +0300] "GET /http://hjh HTTP/1.1" 403 1175 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.55 Safari/533.4"

Comment: @Vitaly: This seems to be a known issue with Windows systems (see https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441).