# Mod Rewrite and passing a URL as parameter

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a small trouble with mod rewrite. A friend of mine is writing a script that allows you to upload images.

What we want to do is allow the user to append a domain name to a direct image link, and the script would retrieve the image from the supplied URL.

For example, if the image is at: http://www.test.com/image.jpg, adding **domain.com**/http://www.test.com/image.jpg would allow a script to retrieve that url (test.com) to get the image we want.

**EDIT:** HTTP is in front of the URL because I don't want the user to have to remove the HTTP manually. They see an image in their browser, they append "domain.com" before it, http and all and the script retrieves that image and stores it on our server.

The rule I am using is:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w|.|/]+(jpg|png|gif))$ /upload.php?url=http://$1 [B,L,NC,R=302]
```

this correctly matches URLs but the colon in http:// causes problems.

If the user inputs: domain.com/www.test.com/image.jpg, it works.

If the user inputs: domain.com/http://www.test.com/image.jpg, it doesn't work and I get a 403 forbidden page (XAMPP on Windows).

If the user inputs: domain.com/http//www.test.com/image.jpg, it works (no colon in http).

**EDIT:** By working, I mean if I test it locally, I get to see the URL I pass in a $_GET['url'] parameter correctly, instead of seeing an error 403.

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this rule and how to fix it? Or any alternative solutions to achieve the behavior we want?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you even need `http://` on the right hand side of the rule?  And what does `works` mean?

Comment: I'll edit the question, so it becomes clearer. Sorry!

Comment: In the apache configuration for your virtual server you should be able to set a mod_rewrite log file and tell apache to log everything when the web service URL is accessed.  I suspect that the error may not be where you think it is.  Google RewriteLog Directive for the version of apache you are using.

Comment: Interesting. When I enable mod_rewrite logging and the colon is there, nothing is written to log. I am assuming it is not getting triggered? When I remove the colon, I see entries in the log.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like something funny is going on.  Jack up the RewriteLogLevel to 9 and see what happens.

Comment: I'm wondering if having http:// in the uri as data is upsetting something.

Comment: Also check the error and access logs

Comment: Logging was set to 9. Nothing happened when I had : there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10865/discussion-between-inf-s-and-peter-m)

Comment: maybe try this: `^((http|https){1})(.+(jpg|png|gif))$` and `/upload.php?url=$2`

Comment: Still 403! I don't think the regex itself is causing an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think I've found the problem. It wasn't the regex, nor mod_rewrite itself.

So it's a bug in Apache on Windows that has been declared WONTFIX.

For reference, see [this StackOverflow thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923247/is-it-possible-to-handle-such-url) and [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441)

I'm posting what I found and will consider this question answered. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You could use urlencode() in php

Answer (score 1):

This approach is cumbersome, error prone and insecure (for example, an image URL isn't required to end with those well known file extensions)

If I understand your use case, it starts when the user is surfing the web and he's viewing an image, and he wants to share it via your service. Then he types by hand `http://your.sharing.service` in the browser's address bar, just before any text. Then you use `mod_rewrite` to trigger your script, but I think your regex (and your service too) will fail in a number of unpredictable ways.

I never used a service like this, and I think that the standard approach of using a button to submit the URL to some script (let's say `http://my.service.com/upload?url=...`) should be preferred.

Comment: That's what I want to do. The inspiration actually comes from reddit. If you encounter a page you want to share, you just append "reddit.com/" in front of the page's URL and it takes you to a page to allow you to share the page. I wanted to do something similar but for images. As for the extensions, it's just for testing purposes. We're only accepting simple images, nothing too complex.

Comment: Yes, but there is a better approach than using regex. For example redirect all kinds of URLs to your script and let it download the resource locally and execute some dummy function just to tell if it's a valid image file

Comment: You mean a sort of controller script? But how do I redirect all kinds of URLs to it, if redirection is breaking as soon as there's a colon in the URL to be redirected. Wouldn't that still be a problem? Is there a way to redirect URLs without mod rewrite?

Comment: BTW, Reddit is for web pages. Usually a site doesn't output the raw image binary data to the browser, instead it responds with an html document. I don't think it's very common to have an image URL in the browser bar (the only case coming to my mind is 4chan)

Comment: We would be expecting the user to append our domain before direct links to images e.g. where the URL ends directly in an image extension. The URL itself is going to a script which will check that the link is actually an image. That's no problem. Firstly, the colon thing has to work!

Comment: I don't know the problem with your regex, but a *catch all* pattern shouldn't give you any. If this is an option, you can also use mod_proxy, which can give you better performance

Comment: I also tested: RewriteRule ^(.)+$ /upload.php?url=$1 [B,L,NC,R=302] and still got the 403 btw. Now if I remove the colon, the URL becomes localhost/upload.php?url=upload.php which doesn't help. Firefox says "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: First, remove all flags except for L. Then I need to know if you are in the server configuration file or inside an htaccess. Anyway I wouldn't use the leading slash (even if it shouldn't hurt in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your regex...

Try:

```
^((http|https)+[\:\/\/\w\.]+(jpg|png|gif))$
```

Comment: Still same. I get a 403 Forbidden error. "You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

Comment: @Inf.S try: `/upload.php?url=$1`

Comment: Rule is: RewriteRule ^((http|https)+[\:\/\/\w\.]+(jpg|png|gif))$ /upload.php?url=$1 [B,L,NC,R=302]

Still 403. It again works if I remove the :.

Comment: @Inf.S Okay (I'm shooting in the dark here): try just: `[R=302]`. Or even just remove all flags for testing's sake.

Comment: please check my comment in the main question regarding logging. It's as if mod-rewrite is not triggering if the colon is there.