# access forbidden on url containing colon symbol, ":", on apache windows

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, localhost

i can't open url with ":" inside url in my localhost
for example, i can't open http://bolehnonton.dev/Halo-4:-Forward-Unto-Dawn (this is in my localhost). the result page in my browser is

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 403 bolehnonton.dev
>   Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12

but i can open similiar url with my hosting, http://bolehnonton.com/Halo-4:-Forward-Unto-Dawn

although htaccess file of both is similiar.

here my vhost configure on my xampp

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@bolehnonton.dev
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/bolehnonton.com"
   ServerName bolehnonton.dev 
   <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/bolehnonton.com>
    Allow from all
     Require all granted
        Options Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it's a server configuration issue, by default most servers allow it. what web server are you using for your localhost?

Comment: He uses Apache/2.4.16 (Win32)

Comment: What rules are currently there? Provide (if so) the httpd.conf (or vhost.conf) file.

Comment: can you open any other urls on your localhost?

Comment: im using xampp on windows 7 64bit @iam-decoder
here my vhost configure

Comment: @AlexAndrei, yes i can open other, just the link with ":" cant open

Comment: URLs cannot contain the character ":", it must be encoded as `%3A`. Start with that premise. Beyond that I'd guess `:` is perhaps a special character in Windows file systems and is treated differently (I don't know Windows though, pure speculation).

Comment: see this answer in particular for a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10440781/5043552. It appears this is an apache bug on windows. The two questions should be merged somehow :)

Comment: You may need to workaround the URL and reformat it using an extra `/` in the URL. or ignore it on windows since that's not your production box anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It is an [Apache bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441) on Windows declared as WONTFIX in 2009. I fixed it in `libapr-1.dll`, function `test_safe_name` in `srclib\apr\file_io\win32\filestat.c` to return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for names with colon.

```
if (*name == '?' || *name == '*')
    return APR_EPATHWILD;
else
    return (*name == ':') ? APR_FROM_OS_ERROR(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) : APR_EBADPATH; // was: APR_EBADPATH;
```

[I could avoid recompiling Apache and patched the binary.](https://www.jurasz.de/blog/apache_colon)

Comment: The patch that was provided in the URL is not working. I am working on PHP application where I cannot change the url. The application works fine on Linux but errors in Windows environment.

Answer (score -2):

I've just encountered same issue with colon in URL.
I was implementing pagination and number of page in URL was specified after colon.

The solution for my situation was replacing colon by another character for develop environment (my windows machine) and leave colon for production (linux machine).

Maybe my story will help somebody.